# Windows Server 2008 R2 editing network settings with powershell

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

my goal is to edit the network settings for MS Windows Server 2008 R2 by Powershell.

e.g.

- IP Configuration with DNS

Is there a way to do it with powershell?

Thanks for your help.

Best wishes,
Stefan

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming. You might be looking for Server Fault if this is a networking problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a little limited with PowerShell on Windows Server 2008 R2.  With the move towards Microsoft's goal of Desired State Configuration (DSC), PowerShell has been expanded beyond belief to allow pretty much anything to be configured using native cmdlets.  However, these come into play with later versions of PowerShell.  You can install PowerShell 5 on Win2k8R2, but the more powerful cmdlets (such as **Set-NetIPAddress**) still won't be available.

If you're running Windows Server 2012 or 2016, progressively more and more options become available.

You may therefore still have to use **NETSH.EXE** from a PowerShell script to do what you want to do.  This is still a perfectly valid option.

Good luck.